# How to connect Canon MG3170 wireless scanner to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, canon, scanner

I'm trying to connect my Canon MG3170 to my laptop via Wi-Fi. So far the printer is working, but scanning isn't. I've tried to use simple scan and sane, but they can't detect the wireless scanner.

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Probably scanning via network isn't available for that model. Most don't allow it and when they do, is directly at the printer/scanner to a configured network share.

Comment: Looks like it's not possible. The workaround I've found so far is via the Canon mobile app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canon supply a programme to run the scanner; it is called ScanGearMP and you can get the debian package that you need; for ubuntu; from here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100394102.html.

You will be downloading scangearmp-mg3100series-1.80-1-deb.tar.gz and if you click to SAVE the package as it is downloaded; it should end up in your Downloads folder; if you open a terminal; ... 3 keys held down .. control alt and t .... and paste the commands below into the terminal; one line at a time, and hit the enter key after each paste;

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf scangearmp-mg3100series-1.80-1-deb.tar.gz
cd scangearmp-mg3100series-1.80-1-deb
```

the next command runs an install script so it should do all that is needed for you: do watch the terminal, as it may ask you some questions and you need to answer them; have your sudo password ready

`./install.sh`

to run scangearmp the first time, you enter `scangearmp` in the terminal and if all is good, you can set up a launcher; either ask here or google