# How to connect Canon MG 5370 wireless scanner to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, scanner, canon

There was a previous [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/919228/541417) to address this same issue for Canon MG3170 wireless scanner.

Adapting the same approach for Ubuntu 16.04.3 and 16.04.4, I have:

- downloaded the package "MG3570 series ScanGear MP for Linux (debian
  Packagearchive)" from [Canon](https://www.canonprinterseries.com/canon-pixma-mg3570/) into folder `Downloads`,
- Done these steps:

in a open terminal:

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf scangearmp-mg3500series-2.20-1-deb.tar.gz
cd scangearmp-mg3500series-2.20-1-deb
./install.sh
scangearmp
```

However, after clicking on `Update Scanner List` button in the scangearmp GUI, it still did not detect the scanner on the Canon MG5370 printer cum scanner.
[image: scangearmp_error]

I am able to print to the printer wirelessly but unable to scan. Neither am I able to use the program "Simple Scan" to scan. However, if I plug Canon MG5370 to my computer via USB, the scanner will work with the program "Simple Scan". My computer is connected to the network via lan.

How can I scan using Canon MG5370 when it is wireless connected to the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "previous answer" that you used as a guide; was for a 3500 series device;

however you have a 5300series device; so the 3500series version of scangear is not going to work; you need the 5300 series from here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100395602.html and is comes down as scangearmp-mg5300series-1.80-1-deb.tar.gz so you can use the format of the commands above; but it would be

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf scangearmp-mg5300series-1.80-1-deb.tar.gz
cd scangearmp-mg5300series-1.80-1-deb
sudo ./install.sh
```

So Simple Scan uses the SANE software; open-source software; and they reckon the 5300 is fully supported; hence it works via usb

networking is more complex; if you first of all run in a terminal

```
cnijnetprn --search auto
```

can you tell us what you get back please

have a read at this post [Troubleshooting Canon scanner over network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988064/troubleshooting-canon-scanner-over-network?rq=1) to give you a feel of what is needed

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It was my mistake. 3500series version of scangear wass not going to work for 5300series. After this correction, scangearmp is now working.

Comment: `$ cnijnetprn --search auto`
`cnijnetprn: command not found`. Seems that `cnijnetprn` isn't install. What should I do next?