# How to Setup Canon MG5370 printer-scanner in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, scanner, canon

Canon MG5370 printer&scanner is connected to the same network as Ubuntu 20.04. Using `Settings` --> `Printers` --> `Add`, Ubuntu 20.04 is able to detect this printer. However, when I try to "Test Print", nothing happens.

I believe this happens because it is using a generic printer driver. See picture below.

[image: printer issue]

On a Ubuntu 18.04 system in the same network, this same printer works and I can see it is using the driver called `Canon MG5300 series - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.13`.

To install this driver, I clicked the `Gear` button and selected `Printer Details`. There after, I clicked `Search for Drivers`. However, it can't find a suitable driver. Next, I  clicked on `Select from Database` --> `Canon` but could not find any `MG` or `MG5300` drivers.

I have also tried [this solution](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/05/canon-printer-scangear-mp-ubuntu-20-04/). Installation was successful but  it could not find the scanner not even when the printer-scanner is connected to the system via usb. See below.

[image: scangear error msg]

Previously, I had [enquired about setting up this same printer's scanner for Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044011/how-to-connect-canon-mg-5370-wireless-scanner-to-ubuntu-16-04). I tried the solution there. Installation of Canon's `scangermp` failed too due to .

```
$ sudo ./install.sh
==================================================

ScanGear MP
Version 1.80
Copyright CANON INC. 2007-2011
All Rights Reserved.

==================================================
Command executed = sudo dpkg -iG ./packages/scangearmp-common_1.80-1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package scangearmp-common.
(Reading database ... 256647 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../scangearmp-common_1.80-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking scangearmp-common (1.80-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of scangearmp-common:
 scangearmp-common depends on libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.8rel); however:
  Package libpng12-0 is not installed.
 scangearmp-common depends on libusb-0.1-4 (>= 2:0.1.10a); however:
  Package libusb-0.1-4 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package scangearmp-common (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 scangearmp-common
Command executed = sudo dpkg -P scangearmp-common
(Reading database ... 256695 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing scangearmp-common (1.80-1) ...
Purging configuration files for scangearmp-common (1.80-1) ...
```

What should I do to setup this Canon MG5370 printer-scanner in Ubuntu 20.04? I want to be able to print and scan.

**Update:**

```
$ driverless
$ driverless list
DEBUG: Started ippfind (PID 25370)
DEBUG: Started post-processing (PID 25371)
DEBUG: PID 25370 (ippfind) stopped with status 1!
DEBUG: PID 25371 (Post-processing) exited with no errors.

$ lpinfo -v
file cups-brf:/
network beh
network http
network ipp
network lpd
serial serial:/dev/ttyS0?baud=115200
network https
network ipps
direct hp
network socket
direct usb://Canon/MG5300%20series?serial=20EE62&interface=1
direct hpfax
network dnssd://Canon%20MG5300%20series._printer._tcp.local/?uuid=urn:uuid:00000000-0000-1000-8000-8887178XXXXX
```

Outcome from following @brian_p answer:

```
$ scanimage -L
device `pixma:04A91754_20EE62' is a CANON Canon PIXMA MG5300 multi-function peripheral
device `airscan:w1:Canon MG5300 series' is a WSD Canon MG5300 series ip=192.168.1.XXX
$ airscan-disciver
airscan-disciver: command not found
$ airscan-discover
[devices]
$
```

**Results For printing:**

`sudo apt install printer-driver-gutenprint` was successfully completed.

```
$ lpinfo -m | grep MG5370
gutenprint.5.3://bjc-PIXMA-MG5370/expert Canon PIXMA MG5370 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.3.3
$ lpadmin -p MG5370 -v dnssd://Canon%20MG5300%20series._printer._tcp.local/?uuid=urn:uuid:00000000-0000-1000-8000-8887178XXXXX -E -m gutenprint.5.3://bjc-PIXMA-MG5370/expert
lpadmin: Printer drivers are deprecated and will stop working in a future version of CUPS.
$ lp -d MG5370 /etc/nsswitch.conf
request id is MG5370-2 (1 file(s))
```

Wireless printing was successful.

Comment: Please give what you get from `driverless`.

Comment: @brian_p What is `driverless`? Thanks for the info in your answer. I will try that and report back.

Comment: It is a command that provides a URI for your printer. Execute `man driverless` for details.  A URI is where a printer job is sent to. It is essential information to know.

Comment: @brian_p I have updated the result from `driveless` to my question.

Comment: Without an output from driverless` I cannot continue my direction to a driverless printing solution. There is another way. Give `lpinfo -v`. Can we get the info to progess with scanning?

Comment: @brian_p I have added outcome from `lpinfo -v`. Where possible, I hope to not need to have to use the serial usb approach to connect my printer to Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I have added printing to my answer and corrected the misspellin of _airscan-discover_.

Comment: For future me... All I had to do was add the IP address of the network MFP scanner (Canon MG2500 Pixma) to /etc/sane.d/net.conf and simple scan could discover it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will tackle scanning first. Printing later. The assumption is that the device is connected to the network.

On Ubuntu 21.04 a user would be given **sane-airscan** by default. You will have to go [here](https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan) and then move on to download a Debian package from [here](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_20.04/amd64/). Install the package and execute `scanimage -L` and `airscan-discover`. Post the outputs back to us.

- The MG5730 is an oldish printer in technical terms. However, it is likely to understand the [WSD protocol](https://wiki.debian.org/SaneOverNetwork#wsd)
- For scanning on USB I would normally recommend [ipp-usb](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_20.04/amd64/), but I do not think it will work with this device.

For printing the network URI is

`dnssd://Canon%20MG5300%20series._printer._tcp.local/?uuid=urn:uuid:00000000-0000-1000-8000-8887178XXXXX`

and the USB URI is

`usb://Canon/MG5300%20series?serial=20EE62&interface=1`

Now install `printer-driver-gutenprint` and do `lpinfo -m | grep MG5730`. The PPD begins *gutenprint* and ends with *expert*.

Execute `lpadmin -p PRINTER_NAME -v URI -E -m PPD`, substituting what you have for URI and PPD. *PRINTER_NAME* can be what you want, for example, *5730*. Test printing with `lp -d PRINTER_NAME /etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: I have uploaded the outcome in my question.

Comment: I confirm that `Document Scanner`, which is very similar to `Simple Scan`, can now scan via wifi. It is WSD flavour. This is great news. However, when I tried to use the same scanner connected via usb, although DS can detected the scanner, the scanned document appears entirely black in colour.  I can't print to printer yet via wifi or via usb.

Comment: You wrote, "_Now install printer-driver-gutenprint_". Do you mean I do `sudo apt install printer-driver-gutenprint`?

Comment: `sudo apt install printer-driver-gutenprint` is fine.

Comment: Printing via wifi is successful. Thank you very much for your guidance. There is a typo in your answer. It should be `lpinfo -m | grep MG5370`.

Comment: Update: I am getting a key error. `GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_20.04  InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23E07629B9E3C9E4 home:pzz OBS Project <home:pzz@build.opensuse.org>` More info [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1392394/sudo-apt-update-an-error-occurred-during-the-signature-verification). How do I fix this issue?