# sudo apt update An error occurred during the signature verification

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates

How do I solve this `sudo apt update` error?

```
Err:9 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_20.04  InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23E07629B9E3C9E4 home:pzz OBS Project <home:pzz@build.opensuse.org>
Fetched 2,441 B in 3s (819 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
19 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_20.04  InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23E07629B9E3C9E4 home:pzz OBS Project <home:pzz@build.opensuse.org>
W: Failed to fetch http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_20.04/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23E07629B9E3C9E4 home:pzz OBS Project <home:pzz@build.opensuse.org>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried solutions from post  [How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey) but they did not work:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 23E07629B9E3C9E4
[sudo] password for master: 
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.QYq1pmnpyE/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 23E07629B9E3C9E4
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv ^C
$ 23E07629B9E3C9E4^C
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 23E07629B9E3C9E4
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data
```

Comment: Not a duplicate: The target Q&A addresses the absence of key, however, here key is expired. Here [The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1397BC53640DB551](https://askubuntu.com/q/1133199/816190) is related Q&A, I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have added some thirdparty [repository](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3Apzz&package=sane-airscan#manualUbuntu) to the system. For now its key is expired.

So you have to disable this repository using Software & Updates.

Comment: It worked. But how do i actually fix the invalid key issue? Is this something for me to do or for the software developer to fix?

Comment: Fix from software developer is needed.

Comment: Noted. I will inform the developer.

Answer (score 1):

Just update the expired gpg key:

curl -fsSL https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:pzz/xUbuntu_20.04/Release.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home_pzz.gpg > /dev/null

source:
https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3Apzz&package=sane-airscan